Laser Scan Matcher Delay
I am receiving the following repeated error message when laser scan matcher is run:
[ WARN] [1728333571.670903467]: Could not get base to fixed frame transform, Lookup would require extrapolation 0.086162303s into the future.  Requested time 1728333571.444619656 but the latest data is at time 1728333571.358457327, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [odom]
I have two questions:

The laser scan matcher is the package in this case that would publish the base link to odom transform so wouldn't it be trivial if this was provided at the given time? This is the result of what is trying to be found. Thus, how can this message be resolved when, to my knowledge, this "latest data" is the most recent laser_scan_match tf output and the current tf output is trying to be found?

More importantly, note the current time (1728333571.670903467) and the requested time (1728333571.444619656) difference of over 200 ms. This is too significant of a delay for my application. Is this a normal delay between the timestamp of the sensor info and the timestamp at which the localization result is obtained? Is this due to lengthy processing time or something else? The scan data updates every 80-90 ms so is it possible to obtain a localization via the laser_scan_match for every scan? I seem to attempt another localization 90 ms later (see below error message, now at time 1728333571.787966643) but this too is over 200 ms later than the "requested time" of 1728333571.518126965.


[ WARN] [1728333571.787966643]: Could not get base to fixed frame transform, Lookup would require extrapolation 0.073507399s into the future.  Requested time 1728333571.518126965 but the latest data is at time 1728333571.444619656, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [odom]
So why is it that there is an over 200 ms difference between the current time of localization and the time at which the data was taken from? I would like for the localization to be returned (current time) as soon after the sensor data is received (scan, odom) as possible.

those messages are labeled as warning, not as error

@jsotola yes, but they indicate delay issues which seemingly shouldn't exist

have you researched the message text?

@jsotola haven't seen any answers to this issue as it pertains to me
